# How to update a string in function without return value?

Tags: python

```py
def updateString()
    '''you can only edit the code inside the  function'''

    name="cat" 
    print(name)

name="dog"

updateString()

print(name)
```

The output of this code will be

```
cat
dog
```

But my required output is

```
cat
cat
```

Can anyone solve this without "return value"

Comment: You can't cleanly. Returning is typically the best way, so why do you want to avoid it? Without returning, you'd need to mutate an argument that was passed in, or reassign a global.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I'm assuming this is a class exercise requiring the OP to modify a global variable from inside a function.

Answer (score 1):

Use `global`

```
def updateString():
    '''you can only edit the code inside the  function'''
    global name
    name = "cat"

    print(name)


name = "dog"

updateString()

print(name)
```

Answer (score -1):

I loaded your code into Visual Studio Code and did some trial-and-error coding. A rather lame solution would be to call the function twice-
.
.
.
updateString()
updateString()
.
.
.
delete the last print statement, if that is allowed in this case.

Comment: I learnt a lot from phibel's response. I loaded his code into visual studio code and it worked perfectly. Thank you all fpor sharing.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which appears to be an exercise that only allows the body of the function to be modified. Returning a value won't help, since the calling code ignores the return value.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).